# Write Informations into existing csv

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

My existing csv looks like this:

```
"Name","Surename","Workstation"
"Doe","John","PC1"
"Fonzarelli","Arthur","PC4"
"Tribbiani","Joey","PC77"
```

Now, I want to check whether the host is online or not and write a new column named "Status" with the result into my csv.

```
$file = Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\WS-Status.csv"

Foreach ($ws in $file) {

    If (Test-Connection $ws.Workstation -Count 1 -Quiet) {

        Write-Host $ws.Workstation "is online"
    }

    Else {Write-Host $ws.Workstation "is offline"}

}
```

It works fine in the console, but how the heck can I export the result into my csv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Add-Member` cmdlet to add a member (status) to your current entity:

```
$file = Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\WS-Status.csv"
Foreach ($ws in $file) 
{
    if (Test-Connection $ws.Workstation -Count 1 -Quiet) 
    {
        Add-Member -InputObject $ws -NotePropertyName "Status" -NotePropertyValue "online"
    }
    else 
    {
        Add-Member -InputObject $ws -NotePropertyName "Status" -NotePropertyValue "offline"
    }
}

$file | Export-Csv "C:\Scripts\WS-Status.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a `PSCustomObject` within your`ForEach` loop:

```
$file = Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\WS-Status.csv"

Foreach ($ws in $file) {

    if(Test-Connection $ws.Workstation -Count 1 -Quiet){
        Write-Host $ws.Workstation "is online"
        $status = "Online"
    }else{
        Write-Host $ws.Workstation "is offline"
        $status = "Offline"
    }

    [array]$result += [PSCustomObject] @{
        Name        = $ws.Name
        Surename    = $ws.Surename
        Workstation = $ws.Workstation
        Status      = $status
    }

}

$result | Export-Csv thing.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Out-File cmdlet which enables you to send pipelined output directly to a text file.

```
$file = Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\WS-Status.csv"

Foreach ($ws in $file) {

    If (Test-Connection $ws.Workstation -Count 1 -Quiet) {
      $ws.Workstation + " is online" | Out-File -Append OutPutFile.csv
    }
    Else {
       $ws.Workstation + ' is offline' | Out-File -Append OutPutFile.csv
    }

}
```